# Alignment of subfigures using pgfplots with clip=false

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

I am using Ti*k*Z/pgfplots with `clip=false` so that the diagonal line in my "sketch" goes outside the axes' ranges. The problem is that this produces subfigures that are not correctly aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            axis lines=left,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=120,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=120,
            clip=false, 
        ]

        \addplot[] coordinates { (-5,100) (115,100) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (100,110) (100,-5) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (55,-5) (130,105) }; 

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfigure[] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            axis lines=left,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=120,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=120,
            clip=false, 
        ]

        % constraints
        \addplot[] coordinates { (-5,100) (115,100) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (100,110) (100,-25) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (90,-30) (160,70.7) };

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

There are lots of posts here about alignment of subfigures, but none of them seems to fix my problem. For example, I tried using `subcaption` instead of `subfigure`, with the `position` argument set to `t`, but this had no effect --- possibly the bounding box is confused by `clip=false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your figure are aligned -- aligned to the bottom of the figure.  If you desire alignment elsewhere you could adjust your figure so that they are the same size.
One solution would be to ensure that the figures are the same size be "drawing" the line which is the cause of the size difference with a `draw=none` option:

```
\addplot[draw=none] coordinates { (90,-30) (160,70.7) };
```

which yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            axis lines=left,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=120,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=120,
            clip=false, 
        ]

        \addplot[draw=none] coordinates { (90,-30) (160,70.7) };%% <-- Added this.
        
        \addplot[] coordinates { (-5,100) (115,100) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (100,110) (100,-5) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (55,-5) (130,105) }; 

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfigure[] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            axis lines=left,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=120,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=120,
            clip=false, 
        ]

        % constraints
        \addplot[] coordinates { (-5,100) (115,100) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (100,110) (100,-25) };
        \addplot[] coordinates { (90,-30) (160,70.7) };

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```